# surds question grade 8

Tags: exponentiation, radicals

I am a student and I need help answering this question.

Simplify:

$\sqrt{135}$ + $\sqrt{3}$ × $(\sqrt{5})^5$

Thankyou and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$\sqrt{15\cdot9}+\sqrt3({25}\sqrt5)$$
$$3\sqrt{15}+25\sqrt{15}$$
$$28\sqrt{15}$$
EDIT: Try simplifying (bringing numbers outside the surd) until you can no longer simplify..and then Try to see if you can find common surds to perform operations like addition and subtraction